# How can I tell which CakePHP version is a project made with?

Tags: php, cakephp

Is it possible to know the version of CakePHP used to generate a project with only the app code available?

---

My problem:

I downloaded a project made with CakePHP, and I really can't tell which Cake version to use. The files say, e.g. `@version       $Revision: 8004 $`, but this is different in some files. Should I assume that the highest revision (8004) is the correct one to use?

It seems to be from around 2008, so I guess it's a 1.x version.

PD: [Here](http://genderartnet.constantvzw.be/downloads/genderartnet-88.zip) is the code to the project.

Comment: Looks like 1.3 to me from the folder naming conventions. You are going to need to try the 1.3 branch first. If that doesn't work try 1.2

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I regularly open up *my own* old projects and wonder what version of Cake they're using.

Comment: I don't know! I think it is a valid question..

Comment: Probably best to contact the authors, so they can include the correct CakePHP version in the downloads.

Comment: I'm doing that in the meantime @dhofstet, thanks. But I wanted to know if there was a generic way to tell.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I have found that the version, as of CakePHP 2.3.0, is held within a static file under the root Cake lib.

```
bash #: cat $CAKE_ROOT/lib/Cake/VERSION.txt

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ //
// CakePHP Version
//
// Holds a static string representing the current version of CakePHP
//
// CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
// Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
//
// Licensed under The MIT License
// Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
//
// @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
// @link          http://cakephp.org
// @package       cake.libs
// @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
// @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
2.3.0
```

Comment: Too bad in this project there is none such file. But I checked in fresh cake download for 1.2 and it's there!!

Comment: It's so amazing!  I just found out that cake version in my local env is different from development env!  You solved my problem which have been spending my time for about 1 week! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 28):

Edit core.php, add to top:

```
echo Configure::version();
```

Comment: He only has the app source code. So that will just tell him what version of Cake he's trying to run it under. Not what it was made with.

Answer (score 22):

**Simple way  :** Just search for **VERSION.txt** file. Open It  to check the version.

Path for version.txt

For **cakephp  1.*** : cake/VERSION.txt

For **cakephp  2.*** : lib/Cake/ VERSION.txt

For **cakephp 3. & 4.***  : vendor/cakephp/cakephp/ VERSION.txt

Answer (score 19):

For cakephp 3.x find 
\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\VERSION.txt

[image]

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ //
// CakePHP Version
//
// Holds a static string representing the current version of CakePHP
//
// CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
// Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
//
// Licensed under The MIT License
// Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
//
// @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
// @link          http://cakephp.org
// @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
// @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
3.3.2
```

Comment: Works for CakePHP 4 as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm certain this is for CakePHP 1.2.x branch, and not the CakePHP 1.3.x branch.

You can [download a 1.2.x branch from here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags).

The reason I think it's 1.2 is that all the comment headers are `Copyright 2005-2008`, and only the 1.2.x branch uses that date range. Everything in the 1.3.x branch is `Copyright 2005-2010` or newer.

Comment: Great, thanks! But do you know of a way to know that doesn't involve comparing comments in the files? I really miss bundler here :P

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan you can't. You also can't know what version of PHP was used to run the app. You can `assume` it was version X by checking the code to see if they are using PHP4 or PHP5 features, but otherwise unless the author tells you. There is no way to know. This is a reminder not to store your Cake app files separately from the Cake version that runs it.

Answer (score 4):

we can check through following path

Path=root/lib/cake/VERSION.txt

Open version.txt

last line show the version of cakephp

Answer (score 3):

This is the **BEST** way to get it on run time

```
Configure::version()
```

[3.x docs](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Core.Configure.html#_version)

[2.x docs](https://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-Configure.html#_version)

The other way is to look for VERSION.txt

2.x lib/Cake/VERSION.txt

3.x vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt

Comment: These are two different things. Please read the comments to the other answers

Answer (score 2):

On the wellcome page the version is written, we dont need any command to check the version.
If still it a problem, you somehow dont find the wellcome page. you can use

```
echo Configure::version();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875569/how-can-i-tell-which-cakephp-version-is-a-project-made-with/32067738#comment24351428_16878517

Answer (score 2):

In Cake 3x, inside your project directory, type `bin\cake version` (windows) or `bin/cake version`(osx/linux).

Comment: These are two different things. Please read the comments to the other answers

Comment: Then why does it output the exact same version as the stated in VERSION.txt file?? (explained in previous answers)

Comment: Because (I guess) you generated that project with that binary. But the question asks to know what binary generated a project which was generated elsewhere by who knows whom, using most likely a different binary than the one you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

It's like not possible (without going through all the version changes, checking file/folder structures, comments...etc).

AND, it's for good reason IMO.

When I start an app, I build it in the latest release.  But, even by the time it goes public, I'm usually on a new release of CakePHP, and will continue to update it as they come out.  My APP files don't change at all (other than the requested changes per release notes - if any).  Only the cakephp/lib directory changes (and unfortunately, you don't have that).

If you're lucky, and the previous developer keeps their Cake versions in separate folders instead of overwriting, then you might find the version number in your `webroot/index.php` in the `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` line, but in your case, it's not there.

If you do have the actual Cake files (I know you don't, but other people might), then you can look in the `cake/VERSION.txt` file for the version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Also for Linux console you can check your CakePHP version like this.
Change example.com with your domain name.

```
# grep ^[^\/] /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/lib/Cake/VERSION.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

in cake 3.0 from app root directory>>> cat vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt

Answer (score 0):

For Cakephp3, open command line and go to your Project App directory and type `bin/cake`,it will show you something like this *

> Welcome to CakePHP v3.3.5 Console

Which is your **current** cakephp Version.

Comment: That's the binary or environment version, but not the library version from which the project was generated (possibly a long time ago, in a computer far, far away). Check the accepted answer please.

Comment: @Mauricio,This answer also gives you cakephp version.

Comment: @ManoharKhadka Unless `bin/cake` explores your project and detects which (different) version of cake was used to generate it, I think we are talking about different things here. "Welcome to CakePHP v3.3.5 **Console**" is exactly that, the version of the console binary, that is the cake version you are running in that precise moment. But not the cake version that was run when the project was generated.

Comment: @Mauricio Yes of course, I got it now. It gives current cakephp version.

Answer (score 0):

Any PHP Framework using `composer` having version details in `composer.json` file

[image]

Example

```
{
    "name": "cakephp/app",
    "description": "CakePHP skeleton app",
    "homepage": "http://cakephp.org",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.16",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.6.11",//<<< Cakephp Version
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.8.33",
        "cakephp/migrations": "1.8.1",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
        "donatj/simplecalendar": "^0.6.1",
        "davidyell/proffer": "0.6.3"
    },
```