# How to find out the version number in cakephp v3.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, version, cakephp-3.0

I have a set of code using cakephp v3 but don't know exactly which version of 3 it is based on. How can I find this out?

EDIT: There is a somewhat duplicate question but not exactly the same. This question relates specifically to ver3

Comment: Edit core.php, add to the top:

`echo Configure::version();`

You can find out using this way also:
`cat $CAKE_ROOT/lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell which CakePHP version is a project made with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875569/how-can-i-tell-which-cakephp-version-is-a-project-made-with)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The version can be found in

> vendor\cakephp\cakephp\VERSION.txt

OR

> echo Configure::version();

Comment: You can also run `bin/cake`, the first line of output shows the version.

Answer (score 1):

Now there has an easy command to get cakephp 3 version

```
bin> cake version
```